# Python: Using a 3 dimensional numpy array in ITK

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, itk

I have the following problem. I have a 3D numpy array full of floats called scoreMatrix. Now i want to use Itk filters on it like Thresholding filter. Is that generally possible? I tried to convert the numpy array to an itk image and then process it. Is there another way to do it?:

```
    scoreMatrixItk = itk.GetImageViewFromArray(scoreMatrix)

    itk.imwrite(scoreMatrixItk, "scoreMatrixItk")
    PixelType = itk.UC
    Dimension = 3

    ImageType = itk.Image[PixelType, Dimension]

    reader = itk.ImageFileReader[ImageType].New()
    reader.SetFileName('scoreMatrixItk')

    thresholdFilter = itk.OtsuMultipleThresholdsImageFilter[
            ImageType,
            ImageType].New()
    thresholdFilter.SetInput(reader.GetOutput())

    thresholdFilter.SetNumberOfHistogramBins(3)
    thresholdFilter.SetNumberOfThresholds(2)
    thresholdFilter.SetLabelOffset(4)

    rescaler = itk.RescaleIntensityImageFilter[ImageType, ImageType].New()
    rescaler.SetInput(thresholdFilter.GetOutput())
    rescaler.SetOutputMinimum(0)
    rescaler.SetOutputMaximum(255)

    writer = itk.ImageFileWriter[ImageType].New()
    writer.SetFileName('outputImage.tiff')
    writer.SetInput(rescaler.GetOutput())

    writer.Update()
```

But i get the error: KeyError: "itkTemplate : No template [ >] for the itk::ImageFileWriter class"

Do i have to pay attention of some things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short blog [post](https://blog.kitware.com/convert-itk-data-structures-to-numpy-arrays/) about itk<->Numpy conversions. You should combine it with information from this [one](https://blog.kitware.com/itk-python-image-pixel-types/). I think that writing the scoreMatrixItk into a file is unnecessary. You should be able to do `thresholdFilter.SetInput(scoreMatrixItk)`, after perhaps changing the type used in creation of `thresholdFilter`. Since you are using unsigned char, you don't need `rescaler` unless you want to increase intensity range from e.g. 0-50 into 0-255. I don't know why you currently get an error.

Comment: I think it works, at least he creates an output image. But unfortunatley I cant  be sure because if I try to print the thresholdFilter.GetThresholds() it show me empty brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @Dženan's response, there is another issue: you have not specified a file format for `scoreMatrixItk`. The format is determined based on the suffix. So the following line:

```
itk.imwrite(scoreMatrixItk, "scoreMatrixItk.vtk")
```

might prevent you from the error.